# Is it necessary to power-stretch when installing carpet?

Tags: carpet

Is it absolutely necessary to use power-stretch when installing carpet? In my case it is a room 284 x 550cm, I thought power stretcher is mainly for large spaces and in my case a knee-kicker would be just fine?

Thanks.

Comment: How much do you value your knees?

Comment: @MichaelKaras, valid point, however I'm also estimating tools rental cost.

Answer (score 2):

According to CRI (Carpet and Rug Institute, a non-profit industry supported professional standards and certification organization)

> The use of a Power Stretcher is MANDATORY.  Devices used as a substitute for, or an attachment to such devices that penetrate through the carpet backing may cause injury, damage carpet or substrates, or result in inadequate stretch.  Such devices are not acceptable.

They also publish installation standards ([CRI-105 for residential carpet installation](http://cri105.info/)).

Now, the reality is that I **have** installed carpets using just a kicker, but I always had a helper with a makeshift "T" shaped stretcher/holder and this was in small rooms only.

Comment: I agree on all counts, but keep in mind that the room in question is  very small.